# Get data from Azure push notification on Xamarin Forms Page

Tags: azure, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app who gets data from prestashop webservices.

In order to make it work, you need to create a api key on the website and provide it to the app, but I think it will be a big problem to the average user to copy a 32 characters key from web to the app.

So I decided it's a good option to create a azure app service backend with a notification hub, when the user creates the api key, it goes to a xxx.azurewebsite.com paste the key, enter the customer notification hub id showed in the login screen of the app and then a push notification is send it to the app, the api key is captured stored and the user logs in.

I'm following this guide [Add push notifications to your Xamarin.Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-push) but I can't see how can I recive the notification in a currently open screen and capture it in a ViewModel class in the shared project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some sample code that shows how to display a pop-up alert in Xamarin.Forms when you receive a Push Notification on either platform.

## Xamarin.Forms Shared Code

Create a `static class` in the Xamarin.Forms shared code that triggers `DisplayAlert`. Then create a `static` method called `ShowAlert` that can be accessed from our platform-specific projects.

```
public static class PushNotificationHelpers
{
    public static async Task ShowAlert(string alert)
    {
        await Application.Current?.MainPage?.DisplayAlert("Push Notification Received", alert, "OK");
    }
}
```

## iOS AppDelegate

To handle the Push Notification on iOS, you will override the `ReceivedRemoteNotification` method in the `AppDelegate`. The `ReceivedRemoteNotification` method is triggered every time the iOS app receives a push notification.

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : FormsApplicationDelegate
{
    .
    .
    .

    public override async void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication app, NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        // Process a notification received while the app was already open
        await ProcessNotification(userInfo);
    }

    async Task ProcessNotification(NSDictionary userInfo)
    {
        if (userInfo == null)
            return;

        Console.WriteLine("Received Notification");

        var apsKey = new NSString("aps");

        if (userInfo.ContainsKey(apsKey))
        {

            var alertKey = new NSString("alert");

            var aps = (NSDictionary)userInfo.ObjectForKey(apsKey);

            if (aps.ContainsKey(alertKey))
            {
                var alert = (NSString)aps.ObjectForKey(alertKey);

                await PushNotificationHelpers.ShowAlert(alert.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine("Notification: " + alert);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Android GcmServiceBase

To handle push notifications on Android, you will create a class that implements `GcmServiceBase` and overrides `OnMessage`. The `OnMessage` method is triggered every time the Android App receives a notification.

```
[Service(Name="com.sample.evolve.GcmService")] //Must use the service tag
public class GcmService : GcmServiceBase
{
    .
    .
    .

    protected override void OnMessage (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Received Notification");

        try
        {
            //Push Notification arrived - print out the keys/values
            if (intent != null || intent.Extras != null) 
            {

                var keyset = intent.Extras.KeySet ();

                foreach (var key in keyset)
                {
                    var message = intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", key, message);
                    if(key == "message")
                        await PushNotificationHelpers.ShowAlert(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Error parsing message: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

## Sample App

The [Xamarin Evolve app](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve) shows how to implement Push Notifications for a Xamarin.Forms app. I highly recommend perusing the Xamarin Evolve app source code to get a better understanding of the above sample code!

Comment: I've been all morning working with The Xamarin Evolve app, the previous guide I have and some more code... but I can't make it work, I think something has changed in the Azure api or something... I will continue with the app and next year I will take a look on notifications again.